# Is the canonical bundle topologically trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a $n$-complex dimensional complex manifold, we can form its canonical bundle $K_{X,\mathrm{hol}}=\bigwedge^n\Omega_{X,\mathbf{C}}$. Usually this bundle is not holomorphically trivial.

As an oriented real manifold, $K_{X,\mathbf{R}}=\bigwedge^{2n}\Omega_{X,\mathbf{R}}$ is trivial because of existence of a volume form.

Is $K_{X,\mathrm{hol}}$ topologically trivial? (We can still integrate holomorphic forms.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the remark about $K_{X, \mathbb{R}}$ being trivial as an oriented real manifold? I would benefit from this being explained. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AmorFati I think a line bundle $K_{X,\mathbb{R}}$ being trivial means it has a nonzero section. On the other hand, being oriented means locally we can find frames which change in $GL_n^+$, then wedge the frame together to get a volume form, use partition of unity we can find a global nowhere zero volume form, which is the desired nonzero section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not always. Since the canonical bundle is a complex line bundle, it's classified topologically by its first Chern class $c_1 \in H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$, which is also the first Chern class of the cotangent bundle of $X$. There's no reason that this should be zero in general. For example, if $X$ is a closed Riemann surface of genus $g$, then $c_1$ vanishes iff $g = 1$.